# Clarification on close reason

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions

[This question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196268) was closed per the *Authorship of code* reason. However nothing in the question seems to suggest that it is not written by the OP. Were there maybe (now deleted) comments that made clear it was not original code?

Do note that the question can be considered "bad" due to not having the code embedded but this consideration is not mentioned in the close reason.

Comment: When deciding the close reasons [I thought the no code reason should be in the 'lacks concrete code' close reason](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8617). However not many others seemed to agree, :(

Comment: @Peilonrayz I was wondering how the current situation came to be, thank you for bringing this up!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yea that close-reason is a bit difficult. It's two, maybe three different reasons packed into one.

> "**Authorship of code**: Since Code Review is a community where programmers improve their skills through peer review, we require that the code be posted by an author or maintainer of the code, that the code be embedded directly, and that the poster know why the code is written the way it is."

This close reason deals with is posts that:

1. Want a review of someone else's code (like a possible employee that could get hired or not based on the review)
2. Don't have the code embedded in the question (whether for licensing concerns or not knowing better)
3. Don't understand the code presented, or rather: Want an explanation of code.

Since there is a limit on the number of custom close reasons we can use, these three have been squashed into a single one