# Can we do away with “someone else's code” wording?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The other day we got the question [Python - Print the average of a list which is a value in a dictionary [on hold]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/126959/42401).
When I came across this question it was being closed for a *custom* close reason, I can't find it, but the comment they made is:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the point of this site is not to explain your code.

We have a close reason for this. [If your question contains someone else's code…](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3654/42401)
Where it says:

> We also expect you to understand how your code works.
>   If you are seeking an explanation of how your code works,
>   then we will treat the question as if someone else wrote it.

This shows that the close reason *is confusing*.
If two 15k+ users don't vote to close for that reason, then what are new users going to think?
I know, [we've asked this before](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2371/42401), [okay twice](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5354/42401).
*And both times the community have said to do it*.
The second time it seemed to be declined in favour for:
[How should we revise the standard off-topic reasons, if we can have up to five?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5366/42401)
It makes sense, it probably should be two different reasons.
But [it got declined](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29323799#29323799).

> @JoeWallis Community Managers pushed back. We would have to build a stronger case if we wanted more than three.

Can we decide on how we can make this close reason less confusing?

I think we should remove "someone else's".
But we may want to separate the two close reasons and re-ask for a fourth close reason.

---

If we want a fourth of fifth close reason we'd probably have to say why [Robert Cartaino's answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5463/42401) doesn't work, or probably any of those answers.<sup>[Info](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29324148#29324148)</sup>

Comment: All right, I have to say seeing a duplicate marked by a diamond AND a gold badge made me chuckle.